# Can I fly domestically in the US with an emergency passport?

Tags: usa, passports, domestic-travel

I am in California and am flying to New York. I have a regular state issued drivers license, but not a real ID. I also have an emergency passport which is valid until August 2023. Will I be able to fly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fly with the regular driving license until [May 2025](https://www.tsa.gov/real-id). Unless the Real ID requirement gets postponed, again, by that time. You can also fly with the emergency passport, while it is valid, but the driver license would probably be more convenient.

Comment: Given the track record on Real ID implementation… I got my current license right before my state started, and was irritated that I’d have to get a new one well before it expired. Well, the 10 years of validity are up this fall…